# What's the booting differnce Between tensorflow 1.15 "m48" and tensorflow 1.15 "m45"?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

What's the booting differnce Between tensorflow 1.15 "m48" and tensorflow 1.15 "m45"?

I can't find the difference in google. :(

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different releases for Deep Learning VMs can be tracked [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/release-notes). In the release notes should appear the changes that were made; however, the last release note is for M41.

I recommend subscribing to this [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/152495564) to keep updated about when they add the release notes for m48 and m45.

Comment: I had difficulty with finding that kind of website! Thank you~!